# PowerShell split string into two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, multidimensional-array, split

**TL:DR**

Using PowerShell I want to split a string of text first by the new line character (\n), store it into an array, then split those array entries with a comma into a two-dimensional array. I am having trouble accessing (or possibly creating) any information in the second dimension.

**INFO:**

I have the following string (stored as `$services`):

```
SUPER-PC,Microsoft Office ClickToRun Service,ClickToRunSvc,C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeClickToRun.exe /service,Auto
SUPER-PC,Adobe Acrobat Update Service,AdobeARMservice,C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe,Auto
```

**Desired result:**

I want to split the string twice:

1. Split on the new line (first dimension)
2. Split on the commas within the line (second dimension)

I want the end result of this to be a two dimensional array that I can reference. (**Ex:** `$services[0][0]` etc.)

**Commands Used:**

To accomplish the new line split I have been using the following command:

```
$services= $services -split "\n"
```

To access the split string in the new array structure I can do the following:

```
$services[0]
```

PowerShell displays only the first line of `$services`

Next I use:

```
$services[0] = $services[0] -split ','
```

**Problem:**

When I attempt to access the second dimension of the first array using `$services[0][0]` it displays `S` which is the first character of the character array ("SUPER-PC" being the start of the string), not the two-dimensional array I want to create.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I hate to self answer, but this was far more simple than I thought... Both other answers are valid, and Mathias pointed me to an obvious oversight.

`$string = $string -split ","` is **not** the same as `$string = $string.split(",")` As Mathias said:

> `-split` returns an object of type `string[]`, meaning that you can't
>   assign anything other than a string to a single item without changing
>   the type of the entire array.

So I ended up utilizing:

`` $services= $services.split("`r`n") ``

and then

`$services[0]= $services[0].split(",")`

I was then able to successfully access the second dimension of the multi-dimensional array using `services[0][0]`

Also, Bacon Bit's answer is in all likelihood **better** than my answer; my answer just addresses my question in the simplest possible fashion.

Answer (score 6):

`-split` returns an object of type `string[]`, meaning that you can't assign anything other than a string to a single item without changing the type of the entire array.

What happens instead, when the parser sees that you're trying to assign a new array to one of the items in the existing `$services` string array, it automatically converts the new array to a string, concatenated by `$OFS`. Since `$OFS` defaults to a space, you essentially turn this string:

```
SUPER-PC,Microsoft Office ClickToRun Service,ClickToRunSvc,C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeClickToRun.exe /service,Auto
```

into this string:

```
SUPER-PC Microsoft Office ClickToRun Service ClickToRunSvc C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeClickToRun.exe /service Auto
```

---

Instead, create an entirely new array to hold the resulting arrays:

```
$Services = @'
SUPER-PC,Microsoft Office ClickToRun Service,ClickToRunSvc,C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeClickToRun.exe /service,Auto
SUPER-PC,Adobe Acrobat Update Service,AdobeARMservice,C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe,Auto
'@

# I prefer a more OS-agnostic newline pattern
$Services = $Services -split "`r?`n"

# Create a new array, defaults to Object[], so can contain arrays as well
$MultiDimensionalServices = @()

# Iterate over each string in $Services
foreach($ServiceString in $Services){
    # use the unary array operator (,) to avoid flattening the array
    $MultiDimensionalServices += ,@($ServiceString -split ',')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there some reason you're not doing something like this:

```
$ConvertedServices = $Services | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'ComputerName','ServiceDescription','ServiceName','CommandLine','StartUp'
```

And then:

```
$ConvertedServices[0].ComputerName
```

Multidimensional arrays in PowerShell do work, but they're kind of flaky to work with, IMX, especially with strings because strings are often treated as character arrays like you're experiencing here.

Comment: Didn't know about this! I'm still a bit of a noob in powershell :) I'm digesting your answer - thank you!

Comment: Ok - when I run the conversion all I get is two instances of "SUPER-PC" on two lines... Do the headers need to exist within the data already i.e. do I need to have a line of headers as well or are those the values defined in `-Header`?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault.  `-Header` is an array of strings, not a comma delimited string.  I've updated  it.  `ConvertFrom-Csv` assumes the first line is is a header row.  The `-Header` parameter is for defining one for data that doesn't have that.

Comment: I have to say, this works beautifully for CSV data; thank you for providing an answer and revising it :)

Comment: Yeah, there's several tools that make working with CSVs pretty easy in PowerShell.  `ConvertFrom-Csv`, `ConvertTo-Csv`, `Import-Csv`, and `Export-Csv`.  It's very easy to work with data files that way.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$Services=("SUPER-PC,Microsoft Office ClickToRun Service,ClickToRunSvc,C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeClickToRun.exe /service,Auto",
"SUPER-PC,Adobe Acrobat Update Service,AdobeARMservice,C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe,Auto")

$ConvertedServices = $Services | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "," -PropertyNames 'ComputerName','ServiceDescription','ServiceName','CommandLine','StartUp'
$ConvertedServices[0].ComputerName
```