# PowerShell collapses string array into single string when stored as second dimension

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

For some reason PowerShell takes an array of strings and converts it into a single string (or perhaps a character array?) when it is set as the second dimension of a two dimensional array:

Here is the initial output of the `$path` array:

```
PS C:\Users\crd> $path
C:
Program Files (x86)
Common Files
Adobe
ARM
1.0
armsvc.exe
```

The `path[0]` array entry is a string value:

```
PS C:\Users\crd> $path[0]
C:
```

Now we set the first value in the `$test[]` array equal to our string array:

```
PS C:\Users\crd> $test[0]=$path
```

You can see that the entire string array has been merged:

```
PS C:\Users\crd> $test[0]
C: Program Files (x86) Common Files Adobe ARM 1.0 armsvc.exe
```

Why is this? I'm sure Microsoft documented this somewhere but I'm having a hard time finding it.

I would **expect** the output to remain unchanged. Note the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\chris> $test[0][0]
C
```

I would like this to be the same as the `$path[0]` output which was `C:`. Why is this merge occurring?

Comment: What would you expect it to set it to?

Comment: @Sean Revised my question a bit - hope that helps.

Comment: Where does `$path` come from? What type is it? Why do you want to work with multi dimensional arrays?

Comment: What it `$test`, how is this different from [the question you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795607/powershell-split-string-into-two-dimensional-array/37796098#37796098) and why do you keep wanting to re-appropriate and reuse the same variables? :)

Comment: Why not use a hashtable or a powershell object and store the path a string then split it when you need to process?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This is different as yesterday I was successful in storing my data in a two dimensional array structure. This question is directly about why this behavior is occurring.

Comment: @jkdba Hey! I am actually just curious as to why this is happening. I am indeed storing the string in a different data structure and will split it when needed. I just want to understand this!

Comment: @Shrout1 I think you will need to declare your `$test` array. If it is not typed properly powershell will assume a string i believe. Try something like this `$Test = New-Object String[][] (3,3)`. Then you should be able to set like so `$Test[0] = $path`.

Comment: @Shrout1 check out the second answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157179/append-an-array-to-an-array-of-arrays-in-powershell

Comment: @Shrout1 If we are to help you understand, please answer the question: What is `$test`? How did you declare/initialize/assign it before doing `$test[0] = $path`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, he/she would have had to only declared it as so `$test=@()` if you dont this this `$test[0]=$path` would fail with unable to set index of null array. If he had gone further and declared as I mention in my comment above this would not be an issue.

Comment: @jkdba What? Indexing into a zero-length array would surely throw an out of bounds exception.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen correct, that is what I said. What I meant by "this would not be an issue" is the question that was asked, not the zero length array failure.

Comment: @jkdba The only way he could end up with the behavior he sees, is if he has initialized `$test` with a `string[]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114658/discussion-between-jkdba-and-mathias-r-jessen).

Answer (score 0):

you changed your hash of items into a single string value. works as expected.